# VMWare Server Under Linux Secondary NIC connection

Tags: linux, vmware, system-administration, nic

With VMWare Server running under Linux (Debain), I would like to have the following setup:

- 1st: NIC being used by many of the
  images running under VMWare, as well
  as being used by the Linux OS
- 2nd: NIC being used by only 1 image and to be unused by the Linux OS (as its part of a DMZ)

Although the second NIC won't be used by Linux, it is certainly recognised as a NIC (e.g. eth1).

Is this possible under VMWare Server, and if so, is it as simple as not binding eth1 under Linux and then bridging it to the image under VMWare Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can set the desired solution up by rerunning the vmware configuration script.  And doing a custom network setup, so that both NIC's are mapped to your vmware instance.  I would recommend making eth0 the 2nd NIC since it will be easier for Linux to use by default.  Then make eth1 the 1st NIC.

Comment: Just as a side note to this answer, it is worth noting that the second NIC should be visible to the linux system (so that if you type ifconfig, you should see both NICS). But to have the second NIC not used by Linux, you must set its "type" to manual and ifup it.